# Why my button hover transition not working well?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a form, and at the bottom, I made a button to submit the form. I also made some transitions in this button while hovering, but it is not working.

The transition is working something like that: when we hover over it the background color of the button will change, and when we remove it, the background color will be removed. Also, from where we remove the cursor, only there the transition will complete. The following are the codes-

```js
 const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        let btn = btns[i];
        btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
            const x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft;
            const y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop;

            btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
            btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
        }
    }
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .contact-main-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .contact-main-container .bg-vid {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .contact-main-container .overlay {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 calc(clamp(2.5em, 8vw, 8em) * 2);
        padding-top: clamp(5em, 21vh, 12em);
        color: #fff;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-title {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-title h2 {
        font-size: calc(clamp(3.25em, 5vw, 8em) * .667);
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-top: clamp(5em, 21vh, 12em);
        position: relative;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 73%;
        padding-right: calc(clamp(2.5em, 8vw, 8em) / 2);
        /* padding-top: clamp(5em, 21vh, 12em); */
        position: relative;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 1.33em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        padding: 0 2.75em;
        position: relative;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col:nth-child(1) {
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col h5 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 3.4em;
        opacity: .33;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 450;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: .6em;
        line-height: 1.065;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .05em;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col .label {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 450;
        padding-top: 1.66em;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col .label.textarea-label {
        line-height: 80px;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col .field {
        appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1em 0 2em 0;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-weight: 450;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: normal;
        display: block;
        margin-top: -0.33em;
        background: transparent;
        outline: none;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col .field.textarea {
        resize: none;
        padding-top: 0.9em;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .submit-button {
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 80px 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .submit-button .btn {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 19px;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid #42CDE7;
        padding: 14px 55px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: transparent;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .submit-button .btn::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: var(--y);
        left: var(--x);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #42CDE7;
        transition: width 0.7s, height 0.7s;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .submit-button .btn:hover::before {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .submit-button .btn span {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container {
        width: 27%;
        padding-left: calc(clamp(2.5em, 8vw, 8em) / 2);
        position: relative;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .arrow {
        position: absolute;
        width: clamp(0.9em, 1.1vw, 1.1em);
        transform: translateY(-200%);
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .arrow i {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section {
        padding-bottom: 2.5em;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section h5 {
        font-weight: 450;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: .8em;
        line-height: 1.065;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .05em;
        opacity: .5;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section ul li {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 2em;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section ul li a {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        will-change: transform;
        outline: 0;
        color: #fff;
        background: transparent;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section ul li a.email {
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }

    .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section p {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        will-change: transform;
        outline: 0;
        color: #fff;
        background: transparent;
    }



    .submit-button {
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 80px 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    .submit-button .btn {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 19px;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid #42CDE7;
        padding: 14px 55px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: transparent;
    }

    .submit-button .btn::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: var(--y);
        left: var(--x);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #42CDE7;
        transition: width 0.7s, height 0.7s;
    }

    .submit-button .btn:hover::before {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .submit-button .btn span {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="contact-main-container">
        <video src="videos/contact-bg.mp4" autoplay="" type="video/mp4" loop="" class="bg-vid" muted=""></video>
        <div class="overlay playvideo" style=""></div>
        <div class="contact-main-sub-container">
            <div class="contact-title">
                <h2>Let's start <br> work together</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-form-sub-container">
                <div class="contact-form-container">
                    <form class="form" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="form-col">
                            <h5>01</h5>
                            <label class="label" for="name">What's your name?</label>
                            <input class="field" type="text" id="form-name" name="name" value="" required=""
                                placeholder="Lorem *">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-col">
                            <h5>02</h5>
                            <label class="label" for="email">What's your email?</label>
                            <input class="field" type="email" id="form-email" name="email" value="" required=""
                                placeholder="lorem@doe.com *">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-col">
                            <h5>03</h5>
                            <label class="label" for="email">What's the name of your organization?</label>
                            <input class="field" type="text" id="form-company" name="company" value="" required=""
                                placeholder="lorem®">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-col">
                            <h5>03</h5>
                            <label class="label" for="email">What's your mobile number?</label>
                            <input class="field" type="text" id="form-company" name="company" value="" required=""
                                placeholder="9876543210">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-col">
                            <h5>05</h5>
                            <label class="label textarea-label" for="message">Your message</label>
                            <textarea class="field textarea" type="text" id="form-message" name="message" rows="8"
                                required="" placeholder="Hello lorem, ... *"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submit-button">
                            <button class="btn custom-cursor" data-btn type="submit">
                                <span>Send it!</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="contact-details-container">
                    <div class="arrow">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-details contact-section">
                        <h5>contact details</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="mailto:lorem@gmail.com" class="email">info@example.com</a></li>
                            <li><a href="tel:+919876543210" class="number">+91-9876543210</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="location contact-section">
                        <h5>location</h5>
                        <p class="location"> Location India</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-media contact-section">
                        <h5>socials</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="" class="lkd">linkedln</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The button alone is working perfectly. There might be some problem with your css with code other than button

Comment: the button also works fine on my side

Comment: The button is working fine alone but if you give top (like top 80vh) it will not works

Answer (score 0):

I think beacuse you didnt declare the i in the for loop (you should say let i = 0)
try that out, write the code base on the i. now your loop doesn't work at all‍♀️.
mybe your bug will fix.
also you can write the event like:
btn.addEventListener("onmousemove", function () {your code}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('custom-cursor');

  btn.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    var rect = btn.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = (event.clientX - rect.left);
    var y = (event.clientY - rect.top);
    btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
    btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
  });
```

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .contact-main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .contact-main-container .bg-vid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  .contact-main-container .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 calc(clamp(2.5em, 8vw, 8em) * 2);
    padding-top: clamp(5em, 21vh, 12em);
    color: #fff;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-title {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-title h2 {
    font-size: calc(clamp(3.25em, 5vw, 8em) * .667);
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: clamp(5em, 21vh, 12em);
    position: relative;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 73%;
    padding-right: calc(clamp(2.5em, 8vw, 8em) / 2);
    /* padding-top: clamp(5em, 21vh, 12em); */
    position: relative;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.33em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    padding: 0 2.75em;
    position: relative;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col:nth-child(1) {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col h5 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 3.4em;
    opacity: .33;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 450;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: .6em;
    line-height: 1.065;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col .label {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 450;
    padding-top: 1.66em;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col .label.textarea-label {
    line-height: 80px;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col .field {
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em 0 2em 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-weight: 450;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: normal;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -0.33em;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .form-col .field.textarea {
    resize: none;
    padding-top: 0.9em;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .submit-button {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 80px 0;
    height: 0;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .submit-button .btn {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #42CDE7;
    padding: 14px 55px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .submit-button .btn::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--y);
    left: var(--x);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #42CDE7;
    transition: width 0.7s, height 0.7s;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .submit-button .btn:hover::before {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-form-container .form .submit-button .btn span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container {
    width: 27%;
    padding-left: calc(clamp(2.5em, 8vw, 8em) / 2);
    position: relative;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .arrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: clamp(0.9em, 1.1vw, 1.1em);
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .arrow i {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section {
    padding-bottom: 2.5em;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section h5 {
    font-weight: 450;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 1.065;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    opacity: .5;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section ul li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 2em;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section ul li a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    will-change: transform;
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section ul li a.email {
    text-transform: lowercase;
  }

  .contact-main-container .contact-main-sub-container .contact-form-sub-container .contact-details-container .contact-section p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    will-change: transform;
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: transparent;
  }



  .submit-button {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 80px 0;
    height: 0;
  }

  .submit-button .btn {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #42CDE7;
    padding: 14px 55px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .submit-button .btn::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--y);
    left: var(--x);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #42CDE7;
    transition: width 0.7s, height 0.7s;
  }

  .submit-button .btn:hover::before {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }

  .submit-button .btn span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="contact-main-container">
    <video src="videos/contact-bg.mp4" autoplay="" type="video/mp4" loop="" class="bg-vid" muted=""></video>
    <div class="overlay playvideo" style=""></div>
    <div class="contact-main-sub-container">
      <div class="contact-title">
        <h2>Let's start <br> work together</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-form-sub-container">
        <div class="contact-form-container">
          <form class="form" method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-col">
              <h5>01</h5>
              <label class="label" for="name">What's your name?</label>
              <input class="field" type="text" id="form-name" name="name" value="" required="" placeholder="Lorem *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-col">
              <h5>02</h5>
              <label class="label" for="email">What's your email?</label>
              <input class="field" type="email" id="form-email" name="email" value="" required=""
                placeholder="lorem@doe.com *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-col">
              <h5>03</h5>
              <label class="label" for="email">What's the name of your organization?</label>
              <input class="field" type="text" id="form-company" name="company" value="" required=""
                placeholder="lorem®">
            </div>
            <div class="form-col">
              <h5>03</h5>
              <label class="label" for="email">What's your mobile number?</label>
              <input class="field" type="text" id="form-company" name="company" value="" required=""
                placeholder="9876543210">
            </div>
            <div class="form-col">
              <h5>05</h5>
              <label class="label textarea-label" for="message">Your message</label>
              <textarea class="field textarea" type="text" id="form-message" name="message" rows="8" required=""
                placeholder="Hello lorem, ... *"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="submit-button">
              <button class="btn custom-cursor" id="custom-cursor" data-btn type="submit">
                <span>Send it!</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="contact-details-container">
          <div class="arrow">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-details contact-section">
            <h5>contact details</h5>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="mailto:lorem@gmail.com" class="email">info@example.com</a></li>
              <li><a href="tel:+919876543210" class="number">+91-9876543210</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="location contact-section">
            <h5>location</h5>
            <p class="location"> Location India</p>
          </div>
          <div class="social-media contact-section">
            <h5>socials</h5>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="" class="lkd">linkedln</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Also explain what did you change in the code. Why the code was not working before

Comment: I have change top and left property respect to button. You take top and left property respect to whole page, that's why its bigger than as expected.